# Typescript do you import `lodash` -- with `es2015` modules?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2, lodash

It used to work, but now I changed my project to `ionic2@RC.0` with its new `rollup` and `es2015` bundling/modules. I'm not able to get `lodash` correctly.

`lodash` is there, but in the wrong place -- the methods I need are in `_.default`

npm steps

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev --save-exact
```

javascript

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
console.log( Object.keys(_) )    // ["default", "__moduleExports"]
console.log(_.default.VERSION)   // 4.16.2
```

What's happening?

**update**

```
import _ from "lodash";  // imports as lodash, not _

// Chrome debugger console:
console.log(_)      // VM2037:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined(…)
console.log(lodash) // function
console.log(Object.keys(lodash))  // returns: VM2075:1 ["templateSettings", "after", "ary", "assign", ...]
```

**update 2**

Maybe it's something with Chrome Debugger + Rollup? I changed my code to `import _ from "lodash";` and it works fine -- except in the debugger console...

```
    console.log(">>> _.keys(_): " + _.keys(_).slice(10, 20));
    // >>> _.keys(_): bindAll,bindKey,castArray,chain,chunk,compact,concat,cond,conforms,constant
    // and the _.sortBy() below works fine
    var sorted = _.sortBy(photos, function (o) {
        return o[sort.key];
    });

   // BUT, in the Chrome debugger (at breakpoint)
   console.log(_)      // VM2037:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined(…)
```

and in fact, when I look at the `main.js` and not the source map, I see signs of tree-shaking(?):

```
        console.log(">>> _.keys(_): " + lodash.keys(lodash).slice(10, 20));
        var sorted = lodash.sortBy(photos, function (o) {
            return o[sort.key];
        });
```

It seems like my problem is with the Chrome debug console, but I'm not sure how to address it...

Comment: `VM1912:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: VERSION is not defined(…)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `import * as` in your import. This will not *select* the defaults.

Use syntax that will import defaults instead:

```
import _ from "lodash"
```

[Here is a link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults)

It seems that rollup attempts to tree-shake the bundle using the static imports.  Therefore, it needs a lodash dependency that is ES6 as well.  Try to install the [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) package instead and then import it:

```
import _ from "lodash-es"
```

Comment: That is marginally better, it imports `lodash` as `lodash`, not  `_`

Comment: This should import lodash as `_`.  Can you show your code?

Comment: @michael very strange!  I'm not familiar with rollup, but that should definitely bind `_` to `lodash.default`.  Very strange.

Comment: @michael I've been reading some rollup posts and it seems that rollup tries to use the static `import` and `export` to *tree-shake* the bundle.  Because of this, most people seem to be saying that you need to `npm install` the [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) package instead of lodash.

Comment: I'm not sure -- it seems to work now if I use `console.log()` statements, but it's not accessible from the Chrome debugger.  But I will try your suggestion with `lodash-es'

Comment: `import _ from "lodash-es";` gives me a `cannot find module 'lodash-es'` error in Typescript, even though I did the `npm install lodash-es --save`

Comment: @michael The Chrome debugger will not see `_` because it is *inside* the bundle's module.  It is not exposed as a global.  This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't you see `_` at a breakpoint set inside the module -- or at least inside the source map?  I suppose the bigger question is, "How do I use the Chrome debugger effectively with `typescript/modules/bundlers`?"